# Listview/Screen is overwriting current Listview/Screen when exiting Searchview

Tags: android, android-activity

Listview/Screen is overwriting current Listview/Screen when exiting Searchview after searching and closing the searchview widget. Mainactivity and SearchAvtivity (class name is ActionBarFragment) are different classes. Here is the image what is happening.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution could be set background of `ActionBarFragment` to white. 
Alternatively proper use of fragmentmanager's backstack can also help.

if its a list fragment, use this line in `onViewCreated()`:

`getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`

or in xml you can use below in root element of fragment's layout xml:

`android:background="#fff"`

Comment: just changing the color they will be disappeared but programmatically they will be there , I think.
So it may interfere with each other listview.